# Using Google Font CSS Rules, But Still Getting "Failed to decode downloaded font"?

Tags: css, node.js, fonts, font-face, google-fonts

May app is self-hosting Google fonts, and using the Google-provided CSS to access them:

```
<style>
    /* roboto-300 - latin */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
        src: local(''),
        url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300.svg#Roboto') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }

    /* roboto-300italic - latin */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
        src: local(''),
        url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300italic.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-300italic.svg#Roboto') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }

    /* roboto-regular - latin */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
        src: local(''),
        url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.svg#Roboto') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }

    /* roboto-500 - latin */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-500.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
        src: local(''),
        url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-500.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-500.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-500.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-500.svg#Roboto') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
</style>
```

...but I'm still getting these errors:

> Failed to decode downloaded font:
> http://localhost:3000/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.woff2 (index):1
>
> Failed to decode downloaded font:
> http://localhost:3000/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.woff2 (index):1
>
> Failed to decode downloaded font:
> http://localhost:3000/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.woff2 (index):1
>
> Failed to decode downloaded font:
> http://localhost:3000/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-500.woff2

How can I correct this?

Comment: Is the system trying to use a fallback font (as it's complaining about .woff not .eot)? What happens if you take out the font-display:swap setting? An what happens if you try loading from google hosting not your own?

Comment: :: It appears I still get the error msg even after Roboto has completed loading, so I don't *think* it's trying to use a fallback font at this point. :: I removed `font-display:swap` but the error is still there. :: If I load the font from Google hosting I don't get the error, but hosting it on my app's server is recommended for faster speed of initial page load.

Comment: Any idea why it would be complaining about woff rather than eot even without the swap?

Comment: I'm a font-load newbie, and don't know the answer to the great question you're asking.  But your comments suggested to me that I should look at other options.  I've implemented this approach - https://www.erichartzog.com/blog/google-font-loading-in-meteor - and it seems to have solved it with good page load scores.